# Adding overload operator == with enable_if

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading, enable-if

I have a working template class point with an overload for `operator==`.

Because of floating point comparison, I was trying to add a second overload with `enable_if` for floating point to use an almost equal function.

This is my attempt:

```
template<typename T>
class Point2D
{
public:
   Point2D(T x, T y);

   Point2D& operator= (const Point2D& point);
   bool     operator==(const Point2D& point) const;
   bool     operator!=(const Point2D& point) const;
};

template<typename T>
Point2D<T>::Point2D(T x, T y) : x_(x), y_(y)
{
}

template<typename T>
Point2D<T>& Point2D<T>::operator=(const Point2D& point)
{
   if(this != &point)
   {
      x_ = point.x_;
      y_ = point.y_;
   }

   return *this;
}

template<typename T>
bool Point2D<T>::operator==(const Point2D& point) const
{
   return (x_ == point.x_) && (y_ == point.y_);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, bool>::type
Point2D<T>::operator==(const Point2D& point) const
{
   return Traits::almost_equal(x_, point.x_) &&
          Traits::almost_equal(y_, point.y_);
}
```

**Note:**

- This is a semplified example.
- The code actually work without the enable_if overload
- I have to separate declaration and implementation (both in .h), so please refer to the code as is.

The error the compiler gives me is

> ```
> error: prototype for typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<_Tp>::value, bool>::type Point2D<T>::operator==(const Point2D<T>&) const
>   does not match any in class Point2D<T>
>   Point2D<T>::operator==(const Point2D& point) const
>   ^
>
> error: candidate is: bool Point2D<T>::operator==(const Point2D<T>&)
> const bool Point2D<T>::operator==(const Point2D& point) const
>       ^
> ```

I don't understand what the error is referring to.

Comment: It's more idiomatic to implement functions of class templates directly in the class (unless they are huge). The error, definition prototype differs with declaration prototype, can be fixed by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, just don't do that.  Do this instead:

```
template<typename T>
class Point2D
{
  bool equals(const Point2D& other, std::true_type is_floating_point ) const;
  bool equals(const Point2D& other, std::false_type is_floating_point ) const;
public:
  Point2D(T x, T y);

  Point2D& operator= (const Point2D& point);
  bool     operator==(const Point2D& point) const;
  bool     operator!=(const Point2D& point) const;
};
```

now:

```
template<typename T>
bool Point2D<T>::operator==(const Point2D& point) const
{
  return this->equals(point, std::is_floating_point<T>{});
}
template<class T>
bool Point2D<T>::equals(const Point2D& point, std::false_type /*is_floating_point*/ ) const {
  return (x_ == point.x_) && (y_ == point.y_);
}
template<class T>
bool Point2D<T>::equals(const Point2D& point, std::true_type /*is_floating_point*/ ) const {
  return Traits::almost_equal(x_, point.x_) &&
      Traits::almost_equal(y_, point.y_);
}
```

this is tag dispatching.  It is cleaner and easier and takes less time to compile than SFINAE enable-if stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear - your definition does not match your declaration. You need the exact same `enable_if` both in your prototype and definition. Also, your `enable_if` will not work, as it needs to happen during **substitution** (SFINAE).

To make things more readable, you can define an alias and use *trailing return types*:

```
template<typename T>
class Point2D
{
   template <typename U>
   using EnableIfFloat = 
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<U>::value, bool>::type;

public:
   Point2D(T x, T y);

   template <typename U = T>
   auto operator==(const Point2D& point) const -> EnableIfFloat<U>&;
   bool operator==(const Point2D& point) const;
   bool operator!=(const Point2D& point) const;
};
```

Definition:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename U>
auto Point2D<T>::operator==(const Point2D& point) const -> EnableIfFloat<U>&
{
   return Traits::almost_equal(x_, point.x_) &&
          Traits::almost_equal(y_, point.y_);
}
```

Comment: You defined operator= instead of operator==, was it a typo?

Comment: I tried:   `template <typename U>
   auto     operator==(const Point2D& point) const -> EnableIfFloat<U>&;` (fixed for ==), and added a cout in both method: `template<typename T>
bool Point2D<T>::operator==(const Point2D& point) const
{
   std::cout << "equal";
   return (x_ == point.x_) && (y_ == point.y_);
}

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
auto Point2D<T>::operator==(const Point2D& point) const -> EnableIfFloat<U>&
{
   std::cout << "almost";
   return Traits::almost_equal(x_, point.x_) &&
          Traits::almost_equal(y_, point.y_);
}`

Comment: in main.cpp:      ` Point2D<double> pd1 = Point2D<double>(0.5,0.5);
   Point2Dd pd2 = Point2Dd(0.5,0.5);
(pd1 == pd2);`  it prints "equal" instead of "almost", so this seems not to work.

Comment: Your template `operator ==` doesn't return `bool`. You have 2 `operator ==`. not sure when templated method can be choosen.

Comment: @Jarod42 indeed the normal operator== seems to be Always chosen.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I guess you missed the const method too

Comment: You forgot a `const` qualifier for the template `operator==`. When will the template `operator==` be called? Even if `T` is float type, the non-template version will be chosen.